# How Google cloud platform manages timezones?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, timezone

I have a database in which I don't know which timezone the times are stored. But I need to know this because I need to generate reports in certain given time zones.

```
select INVOICE_DATE, timestamp(INVOICE_DATE), timestamp(INVOICE_DATE, "UTC+1"),  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), TIMESTAMP(DATETIME (INVOICE_DATE), "UTC-2")
FROM `SALES` s
limit 1000;
```

Whatever Invoice date I have, say today 13:00, when I use UTC+1 it turns it into 12:00; substracting instead of adding hours. I expect it to change to 14:00.

SO I have two main questions.

how can I know which timezone are my times stored?
How can I change the timezones of a given record to match the desired timezone, for example GTM-4?

Comment: What database product are you using?  Where is it hosted?  For your time/date data ... what is the schema type for the tables hosting that data?

Comment: We are using BigQuery on GCP. We use datetime data type an the schema is  2021-10-04T19:16:43  %Y-%m-%dT%T o YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH: MM: SS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datetime data type stores a date and a time.  For example:

October 10th, 2021 at 10:26pm

This is neither a local time nor a UTC time ... it is merely a time specifier.  If you do not know what timezone the data was saved in then you can't specify it as a specific point in absolute time.  When comparing to absolute times, it assumes that the Datetime is UTC.

So ... if my value contains "2021-10-10T22:26:00" and now is UTC 2021-10-10T22:26:00 then if I subtract now-value, the answer is 0.

And ... if my value contains "2021-10-10T22:26:00" and now is UTC+1 2021-10-10T22:26:00 then if I subtract now-value, the answer is 1 hour.

In your example, if your current value is 13:00 and you create a timestamp value that is "2021-10-10T13:00:00" and say that THIS is to be interpreted as UTC+1 ... the you are saying that you are ONE HOUR ahead of UTC and that the time (UTC) would indeed be 12:00.

To prove to yourself ... visit:

https://time.is/UTC+1

and

https://time.is/UTC

For the first link, look at the time shown and say "This is what I would see on my wall clock if I were in timezone UTC+1".  Then visit the second link and say "This would be that same time in UTC".  You will see that UTC+1 is one hour ahead.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. If I Have this TIMESTAMP(INVOICE_DATE, "UTC-2"), I am asking the engine to give me the UTC invoice date, assuming it was in UTC-2 and not asking to convert invoice time from UTC to UTC-2. is that right?

Comment: Right ... if you use "TIMESTAMP(SOME_DATA, SOME_TZ)"  what you are saying is that "Here is a time .. but since time is not an absolute ... meaning that noon in Texas is 5:00pm in London, saying 5:00pm by itself is a relative concept.  If you then say 12:00 UTC-5  (The timezone of Texas), that is the same as saying "12:00 UTC" or "12:00" since the default is UTC.